# How to get JVM in a new process on Android?

Tags: java, android, multiprocessing, java-native-interface

I'm working on an Android project on Android 11. Now I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to generate a new process to run some commands. However these commands will call JNI functions in the new process, where I found it pretty difficult to do so because the new process cannot access my cached JVM pointer in the main process. The function my command will call is like below:

```
static JavaVM* jvm;
static JNIEnv* gloenv;
static jclass glojc;

void PyShowImage(PyObject* obj){
    ...
    jmethodID  showimage = (*gloenv).GetStaticMethodID(glojc,"show_image","([F[II)V");
    ...
}
```

But I can't get JNIEnv and jclass variables in a traditional way because I directly dlopen and run the function from the JNI dynamic library (where JNI_OnLoad won't work). So I have to first get a JVM pointer. Is there a way to get or create JVM in Android 11.0?

Comment: Could you give more details about what you're running in the new process, and what Java code you want to run in it?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I add some detailed codes to the description.

Comment: This all sounds like a massive XY problem. Why are you forking a subprocess in the first place? Can't this flow be replaced by an Android (native) activity?

Comment: Well, I can't replace it with some Android activities since they need to be done in the command shell.

Comment: You can run arbitrary commands from Java (`System.runtime.exec`) so why not?